# how to show radio button only when it has value(geochart)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have the following radio button div

```html
<div id="regionbutton">
  <div id="radio1"><input type="radio" name="region" id="all" value="all" /><label for="all">All</label></div>
  <div id="radio2"><input type="radio" name="region" id="africa" value="002" /><label for="africa">Africa</label></div>
  <div id="radio3"><input type="radio" name="region" id="americas" value="019" /><label for="americas">Americas</label></div>
  <div id="radio4"><input type="radio" name="region" id="europe" value="150" /><label for="europe">Europe</label></div>
  <div id="radio5"><input type="radio" name="region" id="asia" value="142" /><label for="asia">Asia/Middle East</label></div>
</div>
```

and when each button is selected,it will change the 'region' value of each to the options of geochart to display different region.

and the code for that is..

```js
var regions = document.getElementsByName('region');
var defaultRegion = null;
for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
  regions[i].addEventListener('click', drawChart, false);
  if (regions[i].checked) {
    defaultRegion = regions[i];
  }
}
if ((defaultRegion === null) && (regions.length > 0)) {
  defaultRegion = regions[0];
  defaultRegion.checked = true;
}
drawChart({
  target: defaultRegion
});

// radio on 'click' handler
function drawChart(sender) {
  options.region = null;
  if (sender.target.value !== 'all') {
    options.region = sender.target.value;
  }
```

and the code for options of geochart

```js
var options = {
  displayMode: 'regions',
  legend: 'none',
  enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
  resolution: 'countries',
  **region: 'null',
  keepAspectRatio: false,
  width: 800,
  height: 480,
  tooltip: {
    isHtml: 'true',
  }
};
```

but the point is, **how can I show radio button only when it has value to show on that region. Is it possible that we can make something to check if has value on the countries in that region then show the radio button to select.
but if not has any value , **don't show** the radio button to select.**

for now the geochart I created look like this
[image]

but for Africa region , we don't have any data on it.So it look like this[image]

I know that I can just take Africa div out,but it can have any data in the future.

So is there anyway to check data then show radio button to select?

***MORE INFORMATION:*** I query the data from google sheet* you can see my whole code below

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ["geochart"]
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

var data1;

function handleQueryResponseTR1(response1) {
  if (response1.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response1.getMessage() + ' ' + response1.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }
  data1 = response1.getDataTable();
  var colorValues = [];
  var numRows = data1.getNumberOfRows();
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    colorValues.push(parseInt(data1.getValue(i, 15)));
  }
  //assign color to colorValues
  var colorNames = [];
  colorValues.forEach(function(value) {
    if (value <= 1) {
      colorNames.push('#fff09b');
    } else if ((value > 1) && (value <= 2)) {
      colorNames.push('#ffff9b');
    } else if ((value > 2) && (value <= 3)) {
      colorNames.push('#91c1ff');
    } else if ((value > 3) && (value <= 4)) {
      colorNames.push('#3da9ec');
    } else if ((value > 4) && (value <= 5)) {
      colorNames.push('#dfa6ff');
    } else if ((value > 5) && (value <= 6)) {
      colorNames.push('#c1b8b8');
    } else if ((value > 6) && (value <= 7)) {
      colorNames.push('#9edae5');
    } else if ((value > 7) && (value <= 8)) {
      colorNames.push('#d1d19d');
    } else if ((value > 8) && (value <= 9)) {
      colorNames.push('#9edae5');
    } else if ((value > 9) && (value <= 10)) {
      colorNames.push('#9edae5');
    } else if ((value > 10) && (value <= 11)) {
      colorNames.push('#98df8a');
    } else if ((value > 11) && (value <= 12)) {
      colorNames.push('#ffaf87');
    } else {
      colorNames.push('#ffaf87');
    }
  });
  var view1 = new google.visualization.DataView(data1);
  view1.setColumns([16, 15,
    {
      type: 'string',
      role: 'tooltip',
      properties: {
        html: true
      },
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        var country = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 5)
        var policy = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6)
        var dataname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 8)
        var dropname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 9)
        var startdate = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 10)
        var comment = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 12)

        return '<br><div id="country">' + country + " - " + policy + '<br><br></div> ' +
          '<div id="header1">Dominant (E)PR policy model:<br></div>' +
          '<div id="dropname">' + dropname + '<br><br></div>' +
          '<div id ="header2">Since :&nbsp;</div><div id="date">' + startdate + '</div><br><br><br>' +
          '<div id ="comment">' + comment + '<\/div>'
      },

    }
  ]);
  var chart1 = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('colormap1'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'select', function() {
    var selection = chart1.getSelection();
    var cnid = data1.getValue(selection[0].row, 0);
    var polid = data1.getValue(selection[0].row, 1);
    var strid = data1.getValue(selection[0].row, 2);
    var sid = (strid) - 1;

    var statecode = data1.getValue(selection[0].row, 4);
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      //http://www.sagisepr.com/country.php?country=21&polsel=1&sid=17&statecode=AR
      window.open("http://www.sagisepr.com/country.php?country=" + cnid + "&polsel=" + polid + "&sid=" + sid + "&statecode=" + statecode);
    }
  });

  var options1 = {


    colorAxis: {
      colors: colorNames,
      values: colorValues
    },


    backgroundColor: {
      fill: '#FFF'
    },
    datalessRegionColor: '#F5F0E7',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    legend: 'none',
    enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
    resolution: 'countries',
    region: 'null',
    keepAspectRatio: false,
    width: 800,
    height: 480,
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: 'true',
      textStyle: {
        color: '#444444'
      },
      showTitle: false
    }
  };
  //radio button

  // init regions
  var regions = document.getElementsByName('region');
  var defaultRegion = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
    regions[i].addEventListener('click', drawChart, false);
    if (regions[i].checked) {
      defaultRegion = regions[i];
      //console.log(regions[i]);
    }
  }
  if ((defaultRegion === null) && (regions.length > 0)) {
    defaultRegion = regions[0];
    defaultRegion.checked = true;
  }
  drawChart({
    target: defaultRegion
  });


  // radio on 'click' handler
  function drawChart(sender) {
    options1.region = null;
    if (sender.target.value !== 'all') {
      options1.region = sender.target.value;

    }
    chart1.draw(view1, options1);
  }

  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var query1 = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wb0c-eqinhLFgpxuJXKcjdbrnRYaHgqLcsjQerYvl-Q/edit#gid=0");

    query1.send(handleQueryResponseTR1);

  }
```

Comment: nothing in the chart will provide this information, would need to add a column to the data table and check it before rendering the radios...